# What is the significance of a hive log which has a TaskStart line but no TaskEnd line?

Tags: logging, hadoop, cron, hive, bigdata

Some context: I have a cron job set up to do some processing on hive but it's failing right now. The cron log is logging a generic "Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask" error whenever the job is scheduled. More interesting, however, is the hive log files for each of these jobs that are failing. They follow the template:

```
SessionStart [stuff]
QueryStart [stuff]
Counters [stuff]
TaskStart [stuff]
Counters [stuff]
Counters [stuff]
QueryEnd [stuff]
```

Looking at the logs for the jobs that did work, there were firstly far more lines in the logs (which makes sense since this is failing on the first of a series of queries) and secondly every TaskStart line is paired with a TaskEnd line unlike the logs for failed jobs. The equivalent [stuff] seems to match up between the failed logs and the successful logs. The lack of a TaskEnd seems to be the most significant difference which is why I'm asking about it specifically.

This may very well be grossly incomplete information to deduce anything significant but I figured that I may as well ask. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thrift died in the middle of processing.